# Porque meu web component não está sendo criado/renderizado?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

Estou tentando criar um `button` seguindo a documentação [WebComponents](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components) porem meu `button` não está sendo renderizado na página.

Criei um simples `button` que extende os recursos de um `HTMLButtonElement` e aplica um efeito de `ripple` ao ser clicado:

Quando abro a página, apenas o "teste" é renderizado, o meu `web componen`t não é mostrado no template e o `console` não printa a mensagem deixada no `constructor()`.

Porque meu componente não está sendo criado/mostrado?

```js
class MyButton extends HTMLButtonElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log("entrou no construtor");
    this.addEventListener("click", (e) => this.rippe(e.offsetX, e.offsetY));
  }

  drawRipple(x, y) {
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.add("ripple");
    this.appendChild(div);
    div.style.top = `${y - div.clientHeight / 2} px`;
    div.style.left = `${x - div.clientWidth / 2} px`;
    div.style.backgroundColor = "currentColor";
    div.classList.add("run");
    div.addEventListener("transitioned", () => div.remove());
  }
}
window.customElements.define("my-button", MyButton, { extends: "button" });
```

```css
button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fafafa;
  background-color: green
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./my_button.js"></script>
    <script type="stylesheet" src="./my_button.css"></script>
  </head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>web components</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
  <body>
    <my-button>teste button</my-button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é muito simples: não está aplicando o *style* :)

Veja que no css, usou o seletor "button", mas o elemento é criado/renderizado usando a tag "my-button", por isso o seletor deve ter esse nome de tag.

É um simples problema de seletor, isso não é porque foi criar um "novo" button, pode criar um elemento qualquer e estilizar sem que seja preciso um render, isso porque o `HTML` é uma linhagem de marcação, se houver estilo para a marcação, ela será renderizada:

```js
class MyButton extends HTMLButtonElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.addEventListener("click", (e) => this.rippe(e.offsetX, e.offsetY));
  }

  drawRipple(x, y) {
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.add("ripple");
    this.appendChild(div);
    div.style.top = `${y - div.clientHeight / 2} px`;
    div.style.left = `${x - div.clientWidth / 2} px`;
    div.style.backgroundColor = "currentColor";
    div.classList.add("run");
    div.addEventListener("transitioned", () => div.remove());
  }
}
window.customElements.define("my-button", MyButton, { extends: "button" });
```

```css
my-button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fafafa;
  background-color: green
}

meu-novo-elemento {
   display: block;
   border: solid 1px #000;
   border-radius: 30px;
   background-color: #dcf4ff;
   color: #333;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 1.3em;
   padding: 5px;
   margin-top: 10px;
   text-align: center;
   height: 20px;
   width: 100px;
}

meu-novo-elemento:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff
}
```

```html
<my-button>teste button</my-button>
<meu-novo-elemento>Teste</meu-novo-elemento>
```

Veja que se inspecionar o `HTML`, os elementos tem os nomes de tags com os quais foram definidos, por isso o seletor deve acompanhar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**EDIT**:
Sobre o código não escrever no console o que está escrito no construtor (obrigado ao @LuizFelipe pelo comentário), fiz vários testes e cheguei à seguinte conclusão:

> apenas elementos herdados de `HTMLElement` passam "automaticamente"
> pelo construtor quando são registrados, sem passar o parâmetro `{ extends: "tipo" }`.

Isso pode ou não estar certo, mas os testes refletem isso.
Como testei? Criei um código no `jsfiddle` ([está aqui o original](https://jsfiddle.net/ude4zL7r/2/)) que copiei no *snippet* abaixo e pude comprovar isso. Peguei exemplos da internet e criei 3 diferentes WebComponents, herdando de `HTMLElement`, `HTMLButtonElement` e `HTMLParagraphElement`.

Testei nos navegadores Chore, Firefox e Opera e em todos foi o mesmo resultado, no Edge gerou erro ao registrar o component na linha `window.customElements.define`. Em todos os casos de teste, todos elementos só passam pelo contrutor quando é feito `new`, e o elemento é criado manualmente. Só o elemento herdado de `HTMLElement` passa pelo contrutor quando é registrado.  Abaixo o código que exemplificia isso:

```js
class MyButton extends HTMLButtonElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log("construtor MyButton");
    this.addEventListener("click", (e) => this.rippe(e.offsetX, e.offsetY));
  }

  drawRipple(x, y) {
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.add("ripple");
    this.appendChild(div);
    div.style.top = `${y - div.clientHeight / 2} px`;
    div.style.left = `${x - div.clientWidth / 2} px`;
    div.style.backgroundColor = "currentColor";
    div.classList.add("run");
    div.addEventListener("transitioned", () => div.remove());
  }
}

class WordCount extends HTMLParagraphElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log("construtor WordCount");
  }
}

class PopUpInfo extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log("construtor PopUpInfo");
  }
}

// aqui, só o PopUpInfo (HTMLElement) passa pelo construtor
console.log("Registrar os components:");
window.customElements.define("my-button", MyButton, { extends: "button" });
window.customElements.define('word-count', WordCount, { extends: 'p' });
window.customElements.define('popup-info', PopUpInfo);


// aqui, usando new, todos passam pelo construtor
console.log("---------------------");
console.log("Instanciar os components:");

let popup = new PopUpInfo();
document.body.appendChild(popup);

let paragr = new WordCount();
document.body.appendChild(paragr);

let button = new MyButton();
document.body.appendChild(button);
```

```html
<word-count>word-count</word-count>
<br />
<my-button>button</my-button>
<br />
<popup-info>popup-info</popup-info>
```

Comment: Ricardo, você saberia explicar porque o `console.log("entrou no construtor")` parece não estar sendo executado? Isso também me parece uma questão da pergunta.

Comment: olá Luiz. Então não tive tempo ainda de redigir isso na resposta mas, fiz testes com isso e, quando se estende um componente "genérico" de `HTMLElement`, passa pelo construtor, qualquer outro mais específico, como `HTMLButtonElement` não passa, só quando se instancia explicitamente, com `new`, dai o `console.log` não funcionar. Vi vários exemplos disso na internet, todos com construtor usando elementos específicos, mas nos meus testes nenhum funcionou, confirmando o comportamento da pergunta. Vou testar em outros navegadores para confirmar, pq até agora só testei no Chrome

Comment: @LuizFelipe editei a pergunta e coloquei os testes que fiz, foi bem interessante

Comment: Obrigado pelos esclarecimentos @RicardoPontual uma das coisas que notei é que ao usar new() o estilo não é aplicado (acredito que porque neste caso é renderizado no dom com o nome do elemento extendido, exemplo <button> e não <my-button>, estranho.